# Colloquial expression in Berlin?

Tags: phrase

There is an expression in Berlin: "the more east you go, the more east you are". Would it be phrased "je östlicher du gehst, desto östlicher bist du"?

Comment: I live in Berlin and haven't heard that expression yet. The words wou suggest would be a correct translation of your phrase into german, but I don't know (and would rather doubt) whether this is the colloquial Berlin phrase.

Comment: I saw it mentioned in an article about the Marzahn neighbourhood of Berlin, so I thought it might be a thing: https://theculturetrip.com/europe/germany/articles/the-neighbourhoods-in-berlin-to-avoid-in-order-to-stay-safe/

Comment: **Whispered?** When Berliners want to say something, they say it loud and clear, but do not "whisper". As far as I can tell. :-) And if shaved heads and/or Dr Martens were signs of a right-wing conviction - what a terrible world this world would be! I'd say that Dayna Gross blathers.

Answer (score 3):

> There is an expression in Berlin: "the more east you go, the more east you are".

No, that is not an expression in Berlin. I've never heard it and I've lived several years in Berlin.

---

The [article](https://theculturetrip.com/europe/germany/articles/the-neighbourhoods-in-berlin-to-avoid-in-order-to-stay-safe/) says

> The general whispered rule in Berlin is, the more east you go, the more east you are. The Berlin wall didn’t come down that long ago. The further east you go, the more shaved heads you’ll see, and the more Dr Martens.

but means: "the more to the east you go, the more right-wing/ nationalist the people are"

As "east" is on the right side of a map, I get want the author tries to say, but it doesn't make sense in German (and neither in English I think).

In German I would say:

> Je weiter man auf der Karte nach rechts geht, desto rechter sind auch die Menschen.

or

> Der Osten Berlins wählt rechts.

---

If you want to know more about the development of right-wing voting in Germany, I can recommend this article and map: https://interaktiv.morgenpost.de/wo-deutschland-rechts-waehlt/